# Is there a way to use oauth for GAE using postman

Tags: google-app-engine, postman

We're using postman to test our service APIs running on GAE.  In order to authentication, we have to add a header value 'X-Auth' and copy the oauth authentication token used for our login (retrieved from google javascript [library](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference)). We have to do this a lot because the token is rather short lived, so it's a real pain/bottleneck for our developers.

I've been looking into using the postman oauth authentication and even got it working... sort of.  I successfully configured the oauth and logged myself in, granting the permissions, etc and received a token.  However postman wants to put this token into the header not as 'X-Auth' but as 'Bearer' and for whatever reason, authentication is failing.  Perhaps it's because the header name is wrong, perhaps I'm also getting the wrong token value.

So:  Has anyone had success using postman with oauth on GAE?

PS, here's the 'code' Postman is generating :

```
GET /api/XXX/ST_W HTTP/1.1
Host: admin.mycompany.com:8080
Accept-Encoding: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ya29.GmDtA-o7ahRzDFl_kMQZD8n7Y3b38TUg58u3kon6t64JifRhOWNBBd8nsuSJ5-OcZW76xC8j3l9EN39D7Z0860qm1S6IwwwdX0AAvXmQwJZg_mXKQH1r9YZOLmgA95dq9_M
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: a2182695-9b56-1834-5312-3885f2d77426
```

Comment: Have you tried to set a global variable with the token value, and reference it inside the header?

Comment: Not sure how I can do this easily.  I could request the token, then copy the value into a global variable, but that wouldn't save me much.  Besides, I'm coming to the conclusion is the wrong token type... it says ''token_type : Bearer' and I'm not sure GAE can handle that token type?

Comment: as for storing token into variable - it can be done with "Tests"(actually it's mostly "post-response script") section. So you don't have to copy it manually each time.

Comment: I suspect I'm somehow failing to communicate the question.  I can define a header with the X-Auth value, but the token expires after 20 minutes or so.  So then I have to go grab another value and again paste it in.  Postman supports oauth and once you set it up, you can get a token with a simple press of a button.  However, it doesn't supply the correct type of oauth token for GAE.